# Explanation about a problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

[image]

I couldn't get the idea behind *well defined*. What does it mean?

Comment: It means you get the same result for the integral independently of which partition you use.

Comment: In general "well-defined" means the quantity defined is independent of choice a person makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the equation defines a formula pertaining only to two functions $s$ and $h$, $\int s\ \text d h$ in terms of a partition $x_0,...,x_n$. $s$ is a step function, and may have different partitions such that it is constant on each open subinterval of each partition. Saying that the formula is *well defined* means that it gives you the same number no matter what partition (compatible with $s$) you choose. It says that for each partition that makes $s$ constant on open subintervals, the number $\int s\ \text d h$ obtained by the formula is the same.